Installing language packs through lpksetup fails
I am trying to install 6 languages - Serbian, Bulgarian, Chinese(simplified and traditional), Korean, and Romanian.
I have language packs for all of them locally in my system and I am trying to use lpksetup to install them. I cannot install them through language settings because of some restrictions.

I tried sfc /scannow, tried installing using different accounts, checked antivirus settings, tried installing in other servers which are in same network and it worked.
